# How to deploy/copy both an application and resource adapter to Payara Docker image

Tags: docker, activemq-classic, payara

I'm trying to build a Docker image 'from payara/server-full', but I need to copy both my application and an ActiveMQ resource adapter to `$DEPLOY_DIR`.

Following the example at https://hub.docker.com/r/payara/server-full/:

```
FROM payara/server-full:174

COPY domain.xml /opt/payara41/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/
COPY sqljdbc4.jar ${PAYARA_PATH}/glassfish/domains/${PAYARA_DOMAIN}/lib
COPY activemq-rar.rar $DEPLOY_DIR
COPY my-app.ear $DEPLOY_DIR

EXPOSE 8080 8181
```

I'm constantly getting and error in my application:

```
[#|2018-02-23T20:30:09.450+0000|SEVERE|Payara 4.1|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;_TimeMillis=1519417809450;_LevelValue=1000;|
  Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Resource adapter activemq-rar is not deployed
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.getActiveResourceAdapter(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:321)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:166)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainerFactory.createContainer(MessageBeanContainerFactory.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:100)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:209)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:318)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:508)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:570)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:562)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:561)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1851)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1727)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.CommandExecutorImpl.executeCommand(CommandExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.CommandExecutorImpl.run(CommandExecutorImpl.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.runCommand(GlassFishMain.java:235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.doBootCommands(GlassFishMain.java:275)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:104)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:54)
|#]
```

It doesn't appear to be deployed:

```
$ docker container exec -i -t 113e78a53c7a /bin/bash

payara@113e78a53c7a:~$ ls glassfish/domains/domain1/applications

__internal  ejb-timer-service-app  my-app

$ ls deployments/
activemq-rar.rar  my-app.ear
```

Comment: Can you check whether the RAR deploys if you remove your app from the deploy dir? It's possible that the app is being deployed before the RAR as the order is unspecified.

Comment: I'll try that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why RAR isn't deployed may be that the app is getting deployed first. Check the generated `post-boot-commands.asadmin` to see the order of exection of asadmin commands at boot.

To make the deployment order deterministic, create your own post boo commands file and set the docker environment variable `POSTBOOT_COMMANDS` to point to it to use it instead of the generated command file.

Comment: I will check that out soon.  Thanks for the tip. Will get back to you soon.